# Can the specific heat of a substance depend on its amount?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

We define specific heat of a substance as,

$$s=\frac{S}{m}=\frac{1}{m} \frac{dQ}{dT}$$

where $s$ is the specific heat, $S$ is the heat capacity and $m$ is the mass of the substance. Since the derivative of heat $Q$ with respect to the temperature $T$ is not a partial derivative, so I assumed that $Q$ is only a function of the temperature. So the specific heat will als be only a function of the temperature. And there is nothing wrong with this, as the specific heast $s$ can vary with varying temperature for non-ideal gases or even solids and liquids.

Now this got me thinking that can the specific heat $s$ also be a function of the mass $m$. I have not encountered this kind of dependence in any text. However, I am curious to know whether there are cases where the specific heat depends on the mass of the substance. If yes, then please explain why is there the mass dependence. Also, is there any quantitative relation which describes this dependence?

Comment: Specific heat capacity depends on temperature and density or equivalently specific volume or pressure.

Comment: Specific heat is not defined in terms of heat.  It is defined more precisely in terms of specific internal energy, specific enthalpy, and/ or specific entropy.

Comment: @ChetMiller "*Specific heat is not defined in terms of heat. It is defined more precisely in terms of specific internal energy, specific enthalpy, and/ or specific entropy.*" Like the way GiorgioP has defined it in his answer?

Comment: I like his final equation.  You should be aware, however, that specific heat capacity, in general, is a function not only of T but also of one other intensive property.  In the case of an ideal gas or an incompressible liquid, it reduces to a function only of temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it is often written as $dQ/dT$, heat capacitance is not a derivative, in general, and heat is not a function of $T$. It would be more correct to write
$$
C_X = \frac{Q_X}{\Delta T},
$$
where the subscript $X$ identify the kind of process used to transfer the heat $Q_X$, in connection with a change of temperature $\Delta T$.
I have used $C_X$  for heat capacitance instead as $S$ to avoid confusion with entropy (see next sentence).

However, if the heat $Q_X$ is transferred in a reversible way, it turns out that it can be written as $Q=T \Delta S_X$, where now the entropy $S$ is a function of the thermodynamic state.

In the limit $\Delta T \rightarrow 0$, the previous equations  give:
$$
C_X = T\left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial{T}} \right|_X.
$$
Taking into account that, for the usual thermodynamic systems, entropy is an extensive quantity (i.e. proportional to the mass $m$ of the system), it turns out that the  specific heat $c_X = C_X/m$ must be independent on the amount of substance.

Comment: So does an extensive quantity always depend on the mass in a proportional way. Can't it be any other function(like exponential or logarithmic) of the mass?

Comment: @FakeMod No. Usual thermodynamics requires that entropy, energy and all derived thermodynamic potentials should be homogeneous functions of degree 1 of their extensive variables. Since for homogeneous materials mass scales like the volume, other dependences are excluded. There are systems with unusual thermodynamics, non-extensive, but in those cases most of the usual thermodynamic relations have to be revised. If you have a specific case, you may ask a new question.

Comment: Hmm.. I was asking for these kind of unusual materials. But as you said that the thermodynamic relations have to be revised, I think I will leave the question for another day!

Comment: @FakeMod Well, a prototype of system where specific heat is not proportional to the mass is a gravitational system treated as thermodynamic system.  Internal energy does not scale as the volume. However gravitational systms are also  pathological thermodynamic systems, having a **negative** heat capacitance!

Answer (score 0):

The proper equations for defining specific heats, or specific heat capacities, are the following:

$$c_{p}=\Bigl(\frac {\delta h}{\delta T}\Bigr)_P$$
$$c_{v}=\Bigl(\frac {\delta u}{\delta T}\Bigr)_P$$

Where $c_p$ and $c_v$ are the specific heat capacities at constant pressure and volume and have units J/kg.K. To get the heat capacity of a particular object (an extensive property) multiply these by the mass of the object.

These specific heat definitions can be re-written in terms of heat $q$. In the case of $c_p$ we have

$$\delta h=\delta u + \delta pv$$
$$\delta h=\delta q-p\delta v + p\delta v + v\delta p$$

For constant pressure, $\delta p=0$, therefore $\delta h=\delta q$. Substituting into the definition of $c_p$ we have

$$c_{p}=\biggl(\frac{\delta q}{\delta T}\biggr )_p$$

You can do a similar re-write for $C_v$.

For incompressible liquids and solids, the specific heat is generally simply indicated as $c$ since their dependency on specific volume and pressure is considered weak.

It should be noted that all specific heats are a function of temperature, i.e., they are not constant for all temperatures. They are typically specified at room temperature and can be considered approximately constant over a limited temperature range.

> Now this got me thinking that can the specific heat $s$ also be a
>   function of the mass $m$. I have not encountered this kind of
>   dependence in any text. However, I am curious to know whether there
>   are cases where the specific heat depends on the mass of the
>   substance.

For gases the specific heat capacity is not dependent on mass, but rather on pressure and specific volume (or alternatively density). This is why specific heats for gases are specified at constant pressure or volume, $c_p$ and $c_v$, respectively, as shown in the definitions above. The dependency has different ramifications depending on whether it is an ideal or real gas.

As indicated above, for incompressible liquids and solids the dependency of specific heat capacity on pressure or specific volume is weak. Therefore the specific heat for liquids and solids are generally not mass dependent.

> Also, is there any quantitative relation which describes this
>   dependence?

The quantitative relations that describe the dependence on pressure and volume for gases are the ones at the beginning of this answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "*For gases the specific heat capacity is not dependent on mass, but rather on pressure and specific volume (or alternatively density).*" Does this hold true even for real gases?

Comment: Take back my previous comment. Yes it does hold true even for real gases. Both are  not dependent on mass, but rather dependent on specific volume or density. However, that dependency has different ramifications if its an ideal or real gas. For example, $c_{v}=\Biggl(\frac{\delta q}{\delta T}\biggr)_v$. For an ideal gas we can say $\Delta U=c_{v}\Delta T$ since the change in internal energy for an ideal gas is only a function of temperature which in turn only depends on internal kinetic energy. We cannot say that for a real gas as a real gas also has internal potential energy.